# Specifying TCP protocol in JDBC to mysql connection

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tcp

How do you specify that the JDBC connection to mysql in the typical line

```
DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

is via TCP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, TCP will be the underlying protocol despite the nature of the driver used. Unlike Derby or HSQLDB, MySQL does not support (at the time of writing this) any form of databases that operate in an embedded mode.

All connections made to the database for the purpose of executing SQL statements, made by the driver happen to be TCP connections.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a JDBC type 3 or 4 driver.

Even more, as far as I know, all [MySQL JDBC drivers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j.html) are type 3/4 already.

Answer (score -1):

is this what you are looking for?

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8", username, password);
```